Simple Optimization Problem from Economics
An individual has 100 dollars that they have to invest in Asset 1 or 2. The returns from the two assets are $r1\stackrel{d}{=} c + v_1, r2=v2$ for some constant $c$ and independent random variables $v_1\sim f_1, v_2\sim f_2$ with non-negative support. The individual chooses her optimal allocation $x^*$ (for asset 1) to maximize her expected (or average) utility
$$ x^* = \arg \max E_{f_1,f_2} U(x(v_1+c)+(100-x)v_2) $$
where $U'>0, U''<0$
Claim: $dx^*/dc \geq 0$.
That is, as $c$ increases, the first asset would get marginally more attractive, so the optimal investment in asset 1 would (weakly) increase.
To show it formally, I started by taking the first derivative of the objective function that defines $x^*$,
$$ E_{f_1,f_2} (v_1+c-v_2)U'(x^*(v_1+c)+(100-x^*)v_2) =0 $$
And then taking the implicit derivative of the last equation w.r.t $c$,
$$ E_{f_1,f_2} [U' + (v_1+c-v_2)^2 \frac {dx^*}{dc} U'' + (v_1+c-v_2)x^* U'']=0 $$
Re-arranging,
$$ \frac {E_{f_1,f_2} [U' +  (v_1+c-v_2)x^* U'']} {-E_{f_1,f_2}(v_1+c-v_2)^2 U'' }=\frac {dx^*}{dc} $$
The denominator is positive. The first term in the numerator is positive, but I do not know what to do with the second term in the numerator to sign the whole expression. Any hints would be appreciated.
Context: I am trying to write down a simple model of economic behavior.
